# how to fix background image on resize and zoom?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am including a background image on my HTML page. I want it to be fixed across all the screen sizes and on zoom(in/out) as well.

Here is a pen for the problem : **[LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrGjwW)**

The CSS is :

```
body {
  color: #fff;
    background: url("http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Live-Wallpaper-1.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Tell me how should I approach :) xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Np, glad to help :)